# how to make username password in HIve

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, emr, amazon-emr

Currently, in AWS EMR anyone who can ssh to a cluster can use hive and delete/change tables.

How can I manage user permissions on table/schema base?

P.S I have my data on s3 and not on HDFS.

Comment: You need to do it with IAM roles

Comment: Hi Amit. with IAM roles its just access to EMR cluster, and if someone can enter in it. it can also enter hive without any credentials

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implementing-authorization-and-auditing-using-apache-ranger-on-amazon-emr/ might me of your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Lock down the IAM role the EC2 VM comes up as to have no access to anything you don't want to grant to all users.
2. Users working with the VMs should create a set of session credentials and copy them to the VM when they SSH in, so they only get access to their secrets. You should mandate that these are session credentials `(access key, access id, session secret, session ID)` so that they don't accidentally leave their long-lived key on the VM.
3. If you can't do that, you need to take away SSH access to the VMs from anyone who shouldn't be allowed to manipulate the data